# ERROR - JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, error-handling, finance, stock, yahoo

I am using the Code:

```
import yfinance as yf
Infosys = yf.Ticker("INFY.BO")
print(Infosys.info.keys())
```

Till here I am getting an output.
But I am getting an error in the below-mentioned code:

```
Infosys.history(period="5mo")
```

Error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am unable to understand it, please help!!

Comment: Please provide complete error message from start(Trackback) to last.

Comment: `pip3 install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir` looks like this works as per their [github](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/767).